# How to use children prop in Navbar.Toggle component using react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner to frontend development and this is just information related question. I am learning how to use react-bootstrap in my react app. I am unable to understand what the children property is in Navbar.Toggle Component and how can I use it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTN37.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.